# electromagnetic induction. Does charge matter?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics

Just wondering. I know a negative electric charge moving though a coil will induce a voltage in the coil. My question is, would a positive charge, say an ion beam, moving though a coil also induce a voltage?

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_induction#Quantitative), it states that for a tightly wound coil of wire, composed of $N$ identical turns, each with the same $\Phi_B$, Faraday's law of induction states that:

$$
\epsilon = - N  \frac{d \Phi_B}{dt}
$$

So the Electro Motive Force (voltage) $\epsilon$ induced will be proportional to the number of turns $N$.
And be proportional to the rate of change of magnetic flux with time.
Due to the negative sign the EMF will take place in the opposite direction to the change in the flux.

If positive charges are used in stead of negative electrons, then the equation will still hold and assuming the same number, charge, and speed of charge carriers the EMF will be the same magnitude but occur in the opposite direction.